# Wordpress Multisite Installed on subdomain DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, cloudflare, multisite

I have the follow domain:

- domain.com
  There is a Wordpress Multisite installation working properly.

So I want to create a "dev" subdomain to tests purposes, therefore it will be:

- dev.domain.com

I did the backup on domain.com and upload it on dev.domain.com (I did replace all domain instances in database file, changing all domain.com references to dev.domain.com).

I logged with success on dev.domain.com

But when I try to access any subsite, I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.
Example, trying to access site1.dev.domain.com / site2.dev.domain.com... I can't access them.

In cPanel I have already created these subdomains (the same way I have created them for main install).

So, what is the problem? I do need to change something in wp-config or .htaccess?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The error message means the host name could not be resolved via the DNS, so this has nothing to do with your WP config, but with the setup of those subdomains itself. _“In cPanel I have already created these subdomains”_ - and that included automatic setup of the relevant DNS entries as well?

Comment: @CBroe This is working now. I don't know why, but when I create both cpanel subdomain and subsite on wp, it takes a few minutes to go live. Thank you anyway for your attention!